# Maximum depth exceeded but setState should only get called once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a problem here with my code. When the Data is undefined or equals `false` it just has the error `Maximum depth exceeded`. But how does this happen? The setState method should only be called once and if the method sets the state to false, id shouldnt set any states anymore, or not? Where is my error.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.changeLogin = this.changeLogin.bind(this);
    //Loggedin is false
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: undefined
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    communicate("getToken").then(data => {
      //if no data is available
      if (!data) {
        if (this.state.loggedIn === undefined)
          this.setState({
            loggedIn: false
          });
      }
      //Fetch the key
      else {
        let reqBody =
          "refresh_token=" + data.refresh_token + "&grant_type=refresh_token";
        //Fetch via refresh_token
        fetch(conf.apiDomain + "/oauth/token", {
          method: "POST",
          body: reqBody,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF8",
            Authorization: "Basic Y2xpZW50OlRlc3Q="
          }
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(json => {
            //if error exists
            if (json.error) {
              throw new Error("Token not valid");
            } else {
              //save the new tokens in the json file
              communicate("saveToken", json).then(res => {
                //Set the loginstate
                this.setState({
                  loggedIn: true
                });
              });
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            if (this.state.loggedIn === undefined) {
              this.setState({
                loggedIn: false
              });
            }
          });
      }
    });
  }

  //only for the logincomponent
  changeLogin() {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: !this.state.loggedIn
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Decider loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} />
          <Route
            path="/login/"
            render={() => {
              return <Login changeLogin={this.changeLogin} />;
            }}
          />
          <AppRoute
            path="/app/"
            component={Pyl}
            loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}
          />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Error appears at: `if(!data)` if there is no data, if the data is there but invalid, its at the .catch statement

Full Error MSG: `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

StackTrace: https://ibb.co/jZKKJT1

Github for full code: https://github.com/precodeeu/pyl

jsfiddle(works): https://jsfiddle.net/L8anmhvx/3/

Comment: Can you show us the full error?

Comment: I edited the question. If you need more information, please just ask. Thank you! :)

Comment: The problem might be inside `Login` component.

Comment: Thank you! But I was hoping to see the full stack trace of the Stack Overflow. Seems like your App component is fine (AFAIK), but the Login component might be calling `changeLogin()` and causing it to remount, reset, repeat, over and over.

Comment: But where? The error appears in the app.js

Comment: I just added the stacktrace as a screenshot to the question.

Comment: It's not **the** problem, but the `setState` call in `changeLogin` breaks one of the fundamental React rules: You need to use the callback version of `setState` when setting state based on existing state: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: The changelogin method only gets called, when the new token gets saved. So as there is no "new" token, it cant be the login component

Comment: @LukasGermerott - As I said, it's not **the** problem, but it's incorrect and should be fixed.

Comment: How do you use `App`? Looks like something is causing it to mount/unmount in a loop.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I cannot just run that code thing. Its a part of a bigger program. The program is fully available on github. I will edit the github link in the question.

Comment: @LukasGermerott - Please read the [mcve] link provided.

Comment: Okay, I cannot reproduce the error in a jsfiddle. Literally the same code doesnt work in my project. I copy the js fiddle link in the question

Comment: Having critical parts of the question linked in from an external site is a little fragile and is detrimental to the long term value of this question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the real error is coming from `Decider` and your routing.
In Decider when loggedIn = false, it appears you are redirecting back, thus creating the infinite loop.

Comment: But decider doesnt get rendered after you are on the /login router

Comment: Ok, when I ran you code locally that is there error I saw:  `index.js:1446 The above error occurred in the <Lifecycle> component:
    in Lifecycle (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Redirect (at Decider.js:19)
    in Decider (at App.js:95)
    in MuiThemeProviderOld (at App.js:94)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:93)
    in App (at src/index.js:8)`

Comment: Also you're using `componentDidMount()` which occurs *after* render.  `componentWillMount()` is called before

Comment: But componentwillmount is deprecated

Comment: Maybe you are right with that decider loop. I'll try tomorrow

Comment: I think it is just a matter of some reorg.  I know you wouldn't do this in "real life" but in decider you replace `<Redirect to='/login/' />` with ` <Login changeLogin={this.changeLogin} />` you'll see it working...at least no more infinite loop.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow :) I think I have an idea now, but no time to code :)

Comment: So I am trying, but it doesnt work. I have no idea how to reorg that, that my setState doesnt get called that often.

Comment: I know why it isnt working now. Its that I updated react router from 4.3.1 to 5.0.0. On the old version it works perfectly.